# Issues With GSPREAD and Windows Server

Tags: django, iis-8, gspread

I have GSpread working fine locally, but I am getting a 500 error on the server.

I am specially getting an error on this line:

```
 client = gspread.authorize(creds)
```

In my IIS logs I am receiving a 500 0 0 2734 error.

**EDIT: Detailed Error:**

```
Error occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 847, in main 
 result = handler(record.params, response.start)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 177, in __call__
  response = self.get_response(request)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 230, in get_response
  response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 295, in handle_uncaught_exception
  callback, param_dict = resolver.resolve_error_handler(500)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 436, in resolve_error_handler
  return get_callable(callback), {}
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\lru_cache.py", line 100, in wrapper
  result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 115, in get_callable
  mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module

__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named myapp_views


StdOut: 

StdErr:
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please share the details error message when you get 500 error? You could use [fail request tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to see the details error message.

Comment: @BrandoZhang  - I've edited my post to include a detailed error.